# Size of the userProfile folder using PSSession

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with the following segment of code.  I am trying to find the size of the userProfile folder.  This command works perfectly on a local machine.  However when I connect to a PSSession for the servers.  The result I get are completely false.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Pe6.jpg

```
Get-ChildItem c:\users | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| % {$size += $_.Length} 

   write-host "final  size is "$size 
$size =0}
```

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` likely means you are missing 'Access Denied' errors, etc.  If there is an error, then you won't get the size, so the final result will be inaccurate.

Comment: The reason why I have that parameter is or else I get the error 
" that the specified path, file name or both are to long."
The script is launched from an account with administrator rights. my results are significantly to big I would get   800MB instead of 60MB

Comment: So something is definitely going wrong, if you get path errors, so I'd not expect it to be accurate.  For the size being way too big, did you thoroughly test this on a directory you are certain will work and whose size you are sure of?

Comment: Tried to update my post with a picture but was not allowed. (https://imgur.com/a/cInj0HD) here is what I am currently experiencing.  This code snippet works perfectly when I am local. but as soon as I connect to another server using PSSession, it does not work anymore.

Comment: @RamezZaid: If you get "path too long" error messages, doesn't that imply that these paths are therefore not considered and do not contribute to the overall size? In other words: that error alone would explain an incorrect overall size (though there may be other problems).

Comment: @mklement0 correct however that would not explain why my folder size is larger than the truth.  Furthermore, this segment of the script runs well on my local machine, but when I use it in a PSSession thats when it goes bad.  I am trying to find the userProfile size and its not working at all

Comment: @RamezZaid: So even if you use remoting to connect to the very same machine where it works correctly locally you see the problem? Does adding `-Attributes !Hidden, !System, !ReparsePoint` to the `Get-ChildItem` call make a difference (it ignores the legacy folder redirections such as `My Documents`)?